# This policy contains the following error: JSON strings must not have leading spaces

Tags: amazon-web-services, policy, identity-management

I am facing the issue "This policy contains the following error: JSON strings must not have leading spaces"
Here is my code, could anyone help please

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "iam:CreateServiceSpecificCredential",
        "iam:DeleteAccessKey",
        "iam:GetServiceLastAccessedDetailsWithEntities",
        "iam:GenerateServiceLastAccessedDetails",
        "iam:PutRolePermissionsBoundary",
        "iam:ListPoliciesGrantingServiceAccess",
        "iam:UpdateOpenIDConnectProviderThumbprint",
        "iam:ResetServiceSpecificCredential",
        "iam:DeleteSSHPublicKey",
        "iam:ListServiceSpecificCredentials",
        "iam:CreateSAMLProvider",
        "iam:TagSAMLProvider",
        "iam:DeleteRolePermissionsBoundary",
        "iam:GetServiceLastAccessedDetails",
        "iam:GetOrganizationsAccessReport",
        "iam:CreateAccessKey",
        "iam:ListSSHPublicKeys",
        "iam:GenerateOrganizationsAccessReport",
        "iam:ListOpenIDConnectProviderTags",
        "iam:CreateAccountAlias",
        "iam:ListSAMLProviderTags",
        "iam:UploadSSHPublicKey",
        "iam:DeleteAccountAlias",
        "iam:DeleteOpenIDConnectProvider",
        "iam:UpdateSAMLProvider",
        "iam:GetSAMLProvider",
        "iam:ListAccessKeys",
        "iam:UpdateServiceSpecificCredential",
        "iam:UntagSAMLProvider",
        "iam:ListSAMLProviders",
        "iam:RemoveClientIDFromOpenIDConnectProvider",
        "iam:PutUserPermissionsBoundary",
        "iam:GetAccessKeyLastUsed",
        "iam:GetSSHPublicKey",
        "iam:UpdateAccessKey",
        "iam:DeleteUserPermissionsBoundary",
        "iam:UpdateSSHPublicKey",
        "iam:CreateOpenIDConnectProvider",
        "iam:ListOpenIDConnectProviders",
        "iam:ListAccountAliases",
        "iam:UntagOpenIDConnectProvider",
        "iam:GetOpenIDConnectProvider",
        "iam:AddClientIDToOpenIDConnectProvider",
        "iam:DeleteServiceSpecificCredential",
        "iam:TagOpenIDConnectProvider",
        "iam:DeleteSAMLProvider"
      ],
      "Resource": ""
    },
    {
      "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "iam:UpdateAssumeRolePolicy",
        "iam:PutUserPermissionsBoundary",
        "iam:PutUserPolicy",
        "iam:CreatePolicyVersion"
      ],
      "Resource": ""
    },

    {
      "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["iam:CreateUser"],
      "Resource": "*"
    },

    {
      "Sid": "VisualEditor3",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": ["iam:AttachGroupPolicy", "iam:AttachUserPolicy", "iam:AttachRolePolicy"],
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotEquals": {
          "iam:PolicyARN": "arn:aws:iam::758773684219:policy/KodeKloudIAMPolicy"
        },
        "StringNotEqualsIgnoreCase": {
          "iam:PolicyARN": "arn:aws:iam::758773684219:policy/KodeKloudEC2Policy"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I got no errors while creating the policy but it wont let me create the policy as this message pops up "This policy contains the following error: JSON strings must not have leading spaces For more information about the IAM policy grammar, see AWS IAM Policies"

Comment: Your policy appears to be valid JSON, according to an online JSON validator. But you have multiple `"Resource": ""` which are not valid. Did you mean `"Resource": "*"`?

Comment: Be careful when pasting this in the AWS console that there really are not leading spaces before the first `{`.

Comment: It's seems a valid json. Checked with creating policy. As Jarmond mentioned, you have two errors for "Resources" and that's it.